# Can I retrieve usage of cloud services through a c# App?

Tags: c#, amazon-web-services, google-cloud-platform

I'm looking for a way to retrieve performance data of an Amazon/Google cloud services. Specifically, I need CPU and memory usage statistics of the services.
Can I retrieve this information using a C# App?

I tried using CloudTrail and CloudWatch on amazon and nothing... As for Google Cloud not sure where to begin.

Comment: Probably. All major cloud services have REST APIs to use. This post as stated right now is too broad. Do you know how to make REST calls with c#? Have you looked at the documentation for the cloud services you are interested in?

Comment: I have, for example Amazon I can't get the real data, only events or time periods. The ResponseMetada comes empty everytime

Answer (score 1):

Depending on what services you have with Amazon or Google but they both offer API's to retrieve metric data of the instances you're running there. For example [Amazon AWS Docs](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AWSEC2/latest/UserGuide/monitoring_get_statistics.html) or [Google API Explorer](https://cloud.google.com/monitoring/api/apis-explorer).

With the rightAPI you could gather this data using either `System.Net.Http`, `RestSharp` or any other HTTP client.

So start of with looking through those docs on how to get the data. You could use [Postman](https://www.getpostman.com/) to test the API before writing code.